# Why ASP.NET MVC 5 different applications have one authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

1. I create new ASP.NET MVC 5 app, run it and create a new account
   like"admin"
2. I stop IIS dev server and remove my APP.
3. When I create new MVC 5 app and run it, I see "Hello admin", but if I click (go to Account/Manage) I have an error "UserId not found".

Why I see "Hello admin"? My App_Data folder is empty.

Comment: Because of cookies?  When you go to the Account/Manage page, it must hit the database to load details of the user, but as it's no longer there, you get the given error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all localhost web cookie domain is localhost
localhost web A write a cookie name x,localhost web b read cookie name x
when you go manage,it will check in db